# Why does visudo discourage other editors?

Tags: security, sudo

`man visudo` explains that visudo will not (by default) use `EDITOR` or `VISUAL` environment variables.

It states that

> "There is no easy way to prevent a user from gaining a root shell if the editor used by visudo allows shell escapes."

Now I am confused where the security risk lies. 
I believe that

- only root can use visudo to edit `/etc/sudoers`
- only root can change root's environment variables
- root already has a root shell

There is probably a use case where this does not hold, but I can't think of it.

Comment: The short answer is that `sudo visudo` is not equivalent to `sudo su` if the editor does not allow shell escapes, but they *are* equivalent if the shell *does* allow shell escapes.

Comment: If you can edit `sudoers`, you can pretty much do anything you want.

Comment: @jayhendren: As @cjm pointed out, why should anyone but root be allowed to run `sudo visudo` in the first place? Are there any checks to prevent that user from granting itself permission to do `sudo su` that I am missing?

Comment: I don't know for certain, but I wonder if the documentation means that there is a lack of an audit trail when commands are executed from the editor? Not that there is a security hole per se, but that commands can be executed from the editor that will not be individually logged? Much the same as adding permission to run `sudo bash`. That's all I can come up with.

Comment: I believe @mtmiller has hit the nail on the head.

Comment: @mtmiller. The problem: `resolvedit ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/vim /etc/resolv.conf`. This user called `resolvedit` can alter `resolv.conf` using the full path of vim and the file. He can access a shell right after typing `sudo /usr/bin/vim /etc/resolv.conf <ESC> :shell <ENTER>`. Full root shell. Instead, the correct sudoers line would be: `resolvedit ALL=(root) NOEXEC:NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/vim /etc/resolv.conf` to avoid `exec()` calls from a command. There is no way of sudo "check" if a command called another using `exec()`, but he can(if compiled) prevent this call on dynamic-linked binaries

Comment: And i don´t see either why someone would make a "`sudo visudo`" configuration. It is not usefull neither secure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is an additional security risk from running an arbitrary editor from `visudo` strictly speaking. Clearly, the user running `visudo` already has permissions to edit `/etc/sudoers`, and therefore has the ability to add rules that will allow execution of any other commands on the system. So regardless of which editor is run, a user that can `visudo` can already execute whatever they want indirectly by adding a new sudo rule.

I think the advisory in the documentation about the `EDITOR` and `VISUAL` environment variables is about executing a root shell (or arbitrary command) while bypassing sudo's standard logging. By default, sudo logs all successful and unsuccessful authentications to syslog. This gives the system administrator an audit trail about which users are executing which commands through sudo. If a user changes `/etc/sudoers` with `visudo`, that can be seen by checksumming or reviewing the file. However, if a user can get a root shell through `visudo`, they can execute arbitrary commands without any audit trail.

So the security risk is the same as granting permission to run `sudo bash`, namely that a user with that privilege can get a root shell and execute arbitrary code without any restriction or logging of the commands that are run.

Comment: That makes sense. I did not think of the audit trail.

Comment: But - a user *can* get a root shell through `visudo`

Comment: @jalanb if the editor(s) configured to be used by `visudo` allow executing arbitrary commands, yes.